# This React app is not displaying the Zero message when this.state.msg is 0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from './App';

class Car extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super()

        this.state =
        {
            msg: 0
        }
    }


    Increment() {
        this.setState({



            msg: this.state.msg + 1
        })

    }

    Decrement() {
        this.setState({

            msg: this.state.msg - 1
        })

    }
    zero() {
        return this.state.msg === 0 ? 'Zero' : '';

    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <h1> {this.state.msg}  </h1>`

    `
            <button onClick={() => this.Increment()}> Increment</button>

            <button onClick={() => this.Decrement()}> Decrement</button>

            {() => this.zero}

        </div>

        )
    }

    }
    
    
        export default Car;
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.zero`is an arrow function. You need to call it at the end instead of defining it.

```
{()=> this.zero} // You are defining  a function, not calling it

{this.zero()}   // it will execute the method while rendering
```

Your render() contents -

```
 render()

{
  return (<div>
     <h1> {this.state.msg}  </h1>
     <button onClick ={ () => this.Increment()}> Increment </button>
     <button onClick ={ () => this.Decrement()}> Decrement </button>
     {this.zero()}
   </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Hi Tedd, tried doing what you said , it totally worked mr Awesome :-)  ,  Thanks for your time .

Comment: Can you update your render method contents  code with my written code?